# Counting words with pyarrow

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am looking for a performant way to count words with Apache Arrow

I tried

`compute.count(compute.utf8_split_whitespace(table['text'])))`

but that only returns the length of the `compute.utf8_split_whitespace(table['text'])` ChunkedArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to flatten the ListArray returned by utf8_split_whitespace
- `count` counts the number of non null value. You either need [`value_counts`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.compute.value_counts.html#pyarrow.compute.value_counts) or [`count_distinct`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.compute.count_distinct.html#pyarrow.compute.count_distinct) depending on what you want to do.

```py
compute.value_counts(compute.list_flatten(compute.utf8_split_whitespace(table["text"])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also want [value_lengths](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.compute.list_value_length.html), for total word count per scalar.